# get the list of copied in another list of objects

Tags: javascript, html, .net, asp.net-core

```
public async Task PopulateModels()
    {
        try
        {
            var permission = await GetUserPermission();

           **var locations = permission.Permissions[1].ToList();**
            var users = await _userService.GetAllUsers();
            List<UserSelectListViewModel> userSelectListViewModels = new List<UserSelectListViewModel>();
            foreach (var user in users)
            {
                userSelectListViewModels.Add(new UserSelectListViewModel() { Id = user.PkId, Name = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName });
            }
            UserList = new SelectList(userSelectListViewModels.OrderBy(e => e.Name), "Id", "Name");

            locations.Sort((x, y) =>
            {
                var ret = string.CompareOrdinal(x.Name, y.Name);
                return ret;
            });
            var selected = new Model.Location
            {
                PkId = 0,
                Name = "Select Location"
            };
            locations.Insert(0, selected);
            LocationList = new SelectList(locations, "PkId", "Name");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.Message, ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

how i fix the error on  **var locations = permission.Permissions[1].ToList();** this line how should convert to TOList()???

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfZJr.png)
errror Snap

Comment: new List<Permission>().Add(permission.Permissions[1]);

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
var locations = new List<Permission>{ permission.Permissions[1] };
```

You have only one item, so you can create a list and put that item in the list.